# Akka: Tracable logs

Tags: java, logging, akka

I'm using Akka with Java. I want to know is there any best practice/pattern to trace scenarios with logging in Akka environment?

Here is a very simple scenario:

1. A source `Device` actor sends a `status` message to the `Propagator` actor;
2. The `Propagator` actor forwards the `status` message to its listeners (other `Device` actors);
3. Each listener (`Device`) sends an `ack` message to the `Propagator` actor.

Base Requirements:

1. Each running scenario should be distinguishable in logs.
2. The scenario-initiator identifier (here is a device-id) should be presented in all logs.

Any advice for adding to requirements? Maybe the initiating message's class name!?

My approach is putting traceable info in logger's MDC: 1) introducing an interface for marking messages and 2) an Abstract class as a base class of all actors:

1- `Traceable` which is implemented by all (related) message classes:

```
public interface Traceable {

    String traceId(); // An unique id (UUID) in each scenario (Req#1)

    int deviceId(); // Device which initiated the scenario (Req#2)

}
```

2- `AbstractActorWithLogging` as base class of all actors, which puts traceable information in logger's MDC:

```
public abstract class AbstractActorWithLogging extends AbstractActor {

    protected final DiagnosticLoggingAdapter logger = Logging.getLogger(this);

    @Override
    public void aroundReceive(PartialFunction<Object, BoxedUnit> receive, Object msg) {
        try {
            if (msg instanceof Traceable) logger.setMDC(extractMdc(((Traceable) msg)));
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) logger.debug("Received: {}.", msg);
            super.aroundReceive(receive, msg);
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) logger.debug("Processed: {}.", msg);
        } finally {
            logger.clearMDC();
        }
    }

    protected Map<String, Object> extractMdc(Traceable traceable) {
        Map<String, Object> mdc = new HashMap<>();
        mdc.put("traceId", traceable.traceId());
        mdc.put("deviceId", traceable.deviceId());
        return mdc;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know [Jaeger](https://www.jaegertracing.io/) tracing?